# ArithmeticException: using Cipher Algorithm "AES/CFB1/PKCS5Padding" from BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, bouncycastle, jce

I'm trying to create a Cipher algorithm using "AES/CFB1/PKCS5Padding" (BouncyCastle provider), but an ArithmeticException occurs:

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>       at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.getOutputSize(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineGetOutputSize(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)

I just tried to use the default Java Cryptography Extension (JCE), but it does not work with CFB Cipher mode with 1-bit. I need to use the "AES" algorithm with Cipher Mode "CFB 1-bit". It works fine with Cipher Mode "CFB 8-bits" and "CFB 128-bits".

```
private static String buildCipherEncryptCheck(String data){

    byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes();
    String encryptedData = null;

    try {                               
        // Generate valid key
        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");                

        keygenerator.init(128);
        SecretKey myKey = keygenerator.generateKey();           

        // Generate cipher encrypt
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB1/PKCS5Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);                

        // Encrypt the text
        byte[] textEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
        encryptedData = new String(Base64.encode(textEncrypted));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your dataBytes.length == 0

Comment: @puj I'm setted a valid string with length greater than "0".

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how you'd apply PKCS #5 padding to a stream cipher. It might make sense to devise a bit-oriented padding for 1-bit CFB in order to pad out the last byte, but PKCS5Padding (PKCS #7, really) pads with bytes to fill out the final block. But a stream cipher doesn't have a block size. Don't you want `NoPadding` instead?

I suspect that the CFB mode engine is returning 0 as the block size, since it is undefined. When the padding engine tries to use this block size in its computation, the arithmetic error is thrown. (If this is what's happening, it would be better for BouncyCastle to validate the block size and throw a more specific error here.)

Comment: I tried with "NoPadding" and the same error happened. It is a software requirement that I must to work with  "AES" algorithm and Cipher Mode "CFB 1-bit". I tried use the same algorithm configuration with [ruby openSSL lib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) and it work's fine.

Comment: @FernandoChavesBenbassat Okay, what's the exact version of BouncyCastle you are using?

Comment: i'm using: [Bouncy Castle Provider 1.46](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46)

Comment: @FernandoChavesBenbassat I couldn't get the source for that version right now, but the current version has a comment that it only supports CFB modes where the bit length is a multiple of 8. It will allow you to create a cipher instance, but it will fail when used, as you've found. It doesn't look like BouncyCastle offers a solution to meet your requirement for CFB1.